# Jenkins pipelines execution hangs-up after starting npm's http-server via sshPublisher

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline

As a novice to Jenkins I am playing around to learn how to use Jenkins pipelines. My code is written in html and node.js. In a Jenkins deploy stage in the declarative pipeline I copy all required files from the build machine (ubuntu) to the target machine (ubuntu) using Jenkins' "Publish over SSH" plug-in. Works all well, also starting my node application ("node express_01.js &" in a Shell script) using the ssh Publisher sshTransfer execCommand. But when I then start the http-Server (http-server -s -p 3131 . &) execution of the Jenkin pipeline hangs-up. I tried all kinds of variations, e.g. put the http-server start in the Shell script, or even in a separate Jenkins stage. No matter what and where I put the http-server start, Jenkins hangs up. No idea what is so special with the http-server and why it makes hang-up Jenkins' pipeline execution.

Here a pipeline code snippet in which the http-Server is started.

```
    stage('deploy') {
        steps {   
            sshPublisher(
                continueOnError: false, 
                failOnError: true,
                publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(
                        configName: "DeployOnEndor",
                        verbose: true,
                        transfers: [
                            sshTransfer( // stop all running http-server and express_01 node.js services with a sh script first
                                sourceFiles: "build/AAProdDeployStopServices.sh", 
                                execCommand: "cd AngryAlpacaProd/build; chmod +x AAProdDeployStopServices.sh; ./AAProdDeployStopServices.sh" 
                            ),
                            sshTransfer( // then clean up the target production directories
                                execCommand: "rm -r AngryAlpacaProd/*" 
                            ),
                            sshTransfer( // then copy over all executable files and the service restart sh script and run it
                                sourceFiles: "webpages/**/*, node/**/*, build/AAProdDeployStartServices.sh"
                            ),
                            sshTransfer( // make the (node server) start services script executable
                                execCommand: "chmod +x AngryAlpacaProd/build/AAProdDeployStartServices.sh" 
                            ),
                            sshTransfer( // run the (node server) start up process
                                execCommand: "./AngryAlpacaProd/build/AAProdDeployStartServices.sh" 
                            )
                        ]
                    )

                ]
            )
        }
    }
    stage('http-server restart') {
        steps {   
             sshPublisher(
                continueOnError: false, 
                failOnError: true,
                publishers: [
                    sshPublisherDesc(
                        configName: "DeployOnEndor",
                        verbose: true,
                        transfers: [
                            sshTransfer( 
                                execCommand: "http-server -s -p 3131 AngryAlpacaProd/webpages &" 
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ]    
            )
        }
    }
```

Stage "deploy" runs well however stage "http-Server Restart" hangs then infinitely after successful start of the http-server on the target machine. I have to abort the pipeline execution manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, 5min after desparetely posting my question I found a solution: redirecting the output of the http-server into a log-file.

Jenkins pipeline sshPublisher...:
transfers: [
   sshTransfer( 
       execCommand: "http-server -p 3131 AngryAlpacaProd/webpages > AngryAlpacaProd/webpages/http-server.log &" 
              )
           ]

Comment: I had similar issue, I did redirecting both standard input and output but no luck, See I posted issue at  http://5.9.10.113/66963585/why-jenkins-sshpublisher-waits-even-after-remote-command-is-completed    but no response yet